# JNA Different behavior on pcs

Tags: java, c++, dll, jna

i have a java program that works with jna and loads a dll. On my develop computer the program runs without problems. But when i run the program on a different pc i get the error that the program cant find the dependet dlls. But my dll depends only on one dll an this dll is inside the same folder.

I run the program as a jar on Windows 7. Dependency walker shows on both pc the same dependecies.

I dont know what the problem or the difference between those computers is.

Why cant the program load the dll?

Error Message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\THZ-standalone\Dlls\BladeTileLocator.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at de.thz.cameracontrol.utils.Utils.loadLibrary(Utils.java:169)
    at de.thz.cameracontrol.server.Server.<init>(Server.java:124)
    at de.thz.cameracontrol.server.Server.main(Server.java:165)
```

I call the program with java -jar Program.jar.
The dlls are saved in a folder (this folder is in the same folder as the java program).

Here is the method for the libray loading:

```
public static Object loadLibrary(String libraryName, Class<?> clazz) {

final String userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
final String filePathToUse = userDir + "\\" + DLL_PATH;

System.setProperty("jna.platform.library.path", filePathToUse);
System.load(filePathToUse + libraryName + ".dll");

return Native.loadLibrary(libraryName, clazz);
// return Native.loadLibrary(libraryName, clazz);
```

}

I use the statement System.load(filePathToUse + libraryName + ".dll"); for better error messages.

Comment: Do you call your program from within the folder where the DLL is stored? Please provide more information where what is stored and how do you execute it. What is the exception message?

Comment: I have provided additional information.

Comment: **1)** Start your application with `-Djna.debug_load=true -Djna.debug_load.jna=true` to get some information where the JNA library is looking for the DLL. **2)** Shouldn't it be rather `jna.library.path` instead of `jna.platform.library.path`. **3)** Maybe you are mixing 32bit/64bit DLL/JVM?

Comment: I started the programs with your parameters an i get this output:
`Looking for library 'BladeTileLocator'`
`Adding paths from jna.library.path: null`
`Trying BladeTileLocator.dll`
For the 32/64 bit thing: I start the java program in 32 bit mode. I wrap the jar in an exe file. Thanks yes. After chaning from jna.platform.library.path to jna.library.path I get the right path.

Comment: @Freewister it makes sense to put your solution as an answer, and then accept it in two days. That will let people see that the solution exists (and will give you a couple of points as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin of the problem was a wrong name for the JNA library path system property. The right name is `jna.library.path`.

> **1)** Start your application with `-Djna.debug_load=true -Djna.debug_load.jna=true` to get some information where the JNA library is looking for the DLL.
>   **2)** Shouldn't it be rather `jna.library.path` instead of `jna.platform.library.path`.
> **3)** Maybe you are mixing 32bit/64bit DLL/JVM?